# update dll with setup project

Tags: c#, installation

I want to update dll with setup project, because my clients has a program and I want to update this programm, only changing one DLL.

I've create a setup project but can't replace this dll, only put this dll in correct folder if no exist.

Comment: Is the target dll in use with the running program?

Comment: To update the dll, the program is stop

Comment: So what's the problem and what error you receive?

Comment: no exist error. The problem is that I can't replace this dll using install setup. it is possible?